# android HTTP connection refused, Resetting device wifi fixes it but

Tags: php, android

Good day, I have created an android scheduler for a private company with PHP as its back end. There are already tons of post similar to my problem but nothing quite like the one i have, and i have read that i must not post questions on those particular posts, thus created my own.

The login part of my system works on most cases, but there are times when the connection to the host is refused. Mostly when i leave my android device while debugging the system, running it again shows this error.

```
Connection to http://xx.xx.xx.xxx refused
```

I am using a free web hosting site, i have all user permissions on my manifest. As i said, it works 70% of the time. But there are times when i get the above error. Resetting my android device's wifi fixes this error. Is there a better way to fix this error? I am creating this program for a private company after all ... this kind of error, though only appears on rare occasions is not acceptable.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: have you try to implement a retry mechanism in your app?

Comment: i will try to manually retry logging in as soon as i get the error again, if it gets through, ill then add a retry mechanism. Never thought of that, thank you very much.

Comment: perfect timing, i just got the error .... Manually retrying to login does not seem to work. the connection keeps getting refused. Resetting the android wifi worked instantly though.